# How to set part of Json.Net JsonProperty attribute in a derived class without replacing the JsonProperty in the base?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to set a specific JsonProperty (the name) in a base class but also set another (unrelated) JsonProperty in the derived class. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work during serialization and deserialization. The JsonProperty in the derived class completely replaces the JsonProperty in the base class.

How can I still use JsonProperty in the derived class and have the JsonProperty in the base class still be respected during serialization and deserialization?

I have this base class:

```
public class BaseNode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
    public string _sNodeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parentid")]
    [DisplayName("Parent Folder")]
    [DefaultValue("000000000000000000000000")]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    [MinLength(24)]
    public virtual string _sNodeParentId { get; set; }
}
```

This class derives from it:

```
public class BaseBoardNode : BaseNode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Description("Logical name for board")]
    [DefaultValue("newboard")]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public virtual string _sNodeName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ip")]
    [DisplayName("IP")]
    [Description("IP(v4) to use to sync to this board")]
    [DefaultValue("192.168.1.1")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$")]
    public virtual string _sNodeIP { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "port")]
    [DisplayName("Port")]
    [Description("TCP port to use to sync to this board")]
    [DefaultValue(8080)]
    [MinLength(0)]
    [MaxLength(60000)]
    public virtual int _iNodePort { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "devicefamily", Required = Required.Default)]
    [DisplayName("Device Family (Read-Only)")]
    [Description("Device family of board (read-only)")]
    public string _sDeviceFamily { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have 2 final derived classes (maybe more later):

```
public class DefaultingBoard : BaseBoardNode
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public override string _sNodeParentId { get => base._sNodeParentId; set => base._sNodeParentId = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public override string _sNodeName { get => base._sNodeName; set => base._sNodeName = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public override string _sNodeIP { get => base._sNodeIP; set => base._sNodeIP = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public override int _iNodePort { get => base._iNodePort; set => base._iNodePort = value; }
}

public class NonDefaultingBoard : BaseBoardNode
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeParentId { get => base._sNodeParentId; set => base._sNodeParentId = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeName { get => base._sNodeName; set => base._sNodeName = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeIP { get => base._sNodeIP; set => base._sNodeIP = value; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public override int _iNodePort { get => base._iNodePort; set => base._iNodePort = value; }
}
```

When I serialize DefaultingBoard I get this:

```
{
    "_sNodeParentId": "000000000000000000000000",
    "_sNodeName": "newboard",
    "_sNodeIP": "192.168.1.1",
    "_iNodePort": 8080,
    "devicefamily": null,
    "id": "5c93b4b33485788504fcbffb"
}
```

Instead of this desired result:

```
{
    "parentid": "000000000000000000000000",
    "name": "newboard",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "port": 8080,
    "devicefamily": null,
    "id": "5c93b4b33485788504fcbffb"
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to get that desired result (i.e. how to make JsonProperty.PropertyName either not get overwritten or somehow gotten from the base)?

Comment: Can't you just give the `DefaultingBoard` class property `_sNodeParentId` a name alias like you do in the base class? Just add that decoration and set it to parentid `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parentid")]`

Comment: @RyanWilson I can yes. The only problem is that the json name will be duplicated every time I need to use one of those base properties like parentid in a derived class. It would work, just not especially pretty. I was hoping for pretty :D I would have to repeat it for NonDefaultingBoard  and every other derviation.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I solved it. The issue I took with Ryan Wilson's suggestion (in the comment) is that it would result in duplicate code. Like JsonProperty(PropertyName = "keyname") in a couple different places (in each derived class where I wanted to use the same key with different attributes). I was afraid a misspelling or inconsistency would creep into the code sooner or later and bite me.

My work around was to store the key names in constants:

```
public class BaseNode
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public const string _constKeyName_sNodeParentId = "parentid";

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
    public string _sNodeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Parent Folder")]
    [DefaultValue("000000000000000000000000")]
    [MaxLength(24)]
    [MinLength(24)]
    public virtual string _sNodeParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And then re-use the constants in the attributes for key names, instead of typing in the string literally:

```
public class NonDefaultingBoard : BaseBoardNode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = BaseNode._constKeyName_sNodeParentId, Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeParentId { get => base._sNodeParentId; set => base._sNodeParentId = value; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = BaseBoardNode._constKeyName_sNodeName, Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeName { get => base._sNodeName; set => base._sNodeName = value; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = BaseBoardNode._constKeyName_sNodeIP, Required = Required.Always)]
    public override string _sNodeIP { get => base._sNodeIP; set => base._sNodeIP = value; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = BaseBoardNode._constKeyName_iNodePort, Required = Required.Always)]
    public override int _iNodePort { get => base._iNodePort; set => base._iNodePort = value; }
}
```

Then I can use change my key name for parentid in one place and it reverberates all over the code. Plus no foul ups later on.